# Second installation of MySQL without touching first?

Tags: mysql, linux, installation

My problem is this. I have a project where I need to use a MySQL database. However, the computer (a LINUX server) I am dealing with has some other software that is untouchable. This software uses MySQL so it is already installed. However, I don't have the permissions to touch it, nor can I use it. I can't access it because this software is all bundled up for some reason and the network relies on this package working and staying the same.

What I want to know is, can I install a second instance of MySQL (different ports/username/password/etc...) without touching the first one? The tutorials I have found online typically require the first to be modified or at least turned on and off at certain points during the setup of the second.

Thank you for any help or suggestions. I realize it's a rather unusual question...

Answer (score 1):

http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/manually-installing-multiple-mysql-instances-on-linux-howto will help. Read the comments as well -- they link to https://launchpad.net/mysql-sandbox which might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! Sounds great. I'll give it a shot sometime soon.

Answer (score 0):

You could compile mysql from source using:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/mysql
```

or something like that.

That will make sure that the new installation doesn't overwrite/interfere with the old installation.